# Remove similar word bigram and reverting bigram

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

The bigram list that I am able to generate has similar word bigrams and reverting bigrams  for. eg

> (soil, soil), (land, land)     // similar word bigram
>
> (protect, area), (area, protect)  //reverting bigram

How can I remove from my counter list or my bigram list? As I would like to preserve the sequence of the words in the sentence thus, I would not like to remove them from the initial list.

Here is my code

```
texts = [[word for word in text if word not in stopwords] for text in words]
ind_bigrams =[]
  #only bigram generation
for i in texts:
    bgram =list(bigrams(i))
for j in bgram:
    ind_bigrams.append(j)
print(Counter(ind_bigrams))
```

UPDATE

In the above code, texts is the list of the lists of tokens. bgram(again list of list) is the bigram list for each inside list. ind_bigrams is the concatenation of each bgram list as a one list.

Comment: Can you use `ind_bigrams = [tuple(el) for el in frozenset(frozenset(bi) for bi in bigrams(i))]` ?

Comment: no its deleting almost all the bigrams

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough example of what `bgram` contains, what it shouldn't contain and the logic behind excluding those items?

Comment: I have updated the question with the information.